# I want to handle exception in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew();

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have execute an asynchronous method like below

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddAttachment(information.Subject,
information.DocumentId.ToString(),
information.Sender,list.Name));
```

How to handle exception generated inside the method `AddAttachment()`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a continuation task to examine the one you created with `StartNew`:

```
Task outer = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddAttachment(information.Subject, information.DocumentId.ToString(), information.Sender,list.Name))
    .ContinueWith(task => {
        if(task.IsFaulted)
        {
            AggregateException ex = task.Exception;
            //handle exception
        }
    });
```

Comment: is ContinueWith is a callback function?

Comment: @JEMI - Yes, it will be called when the parent task is completed, either normally or due to an error or cancellation. If you only care about errors, you can specify the `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted` option to `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a continuation and use the `OnlyOnFaulted` option:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => AddAttachment(information.Subject, information.DocumentId.ToString(), information.Sender,list.Name))
            .ContinueWith(t => HandleException(t.Exception),
                          TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

This way, the continuation will only be called if an exception was thrown from the original task.

Answer (score 0):

[Task.Exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx) property will contain exception after task finish with exception, for more details check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415.aspx)

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(...
...
task.Exception
```

Comment: I don't believe it will block, "if the Task completed successfully *or has not yet thrown any exceptions*, this will return null".

Comment: Right @sixlettervariables, thanks for correction, I edited the post